# How is the order in which scripts are executed in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: My test result]

In Unity, I was curious about the sequence of execution when using `Awake()` function in many classes, I took a log and I could see the above results.

As a result, the scripts that were first generated, with low numbers, are executed later.
But I couldn't know How or why it is like this...

If possible, can I get some of your knowledge or URL of documents related to this?

ps. I did not change the Script Excution Order configuration.

```
public class TEST1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("TEST1");
    }
}

public class TEST2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("TEST2");
    }
}

public class TEST3 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("TEST3");
    }
}
```

Comment: If my english is strange.. I'm sorry. I was used translator.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many times. Check out https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html, and make sure to do research before asking questions on stackoverflow. Awake is called whenever a script is loaded, or added to a gameobject. Start is called right before the first frame, but not again if later on the script is added to a gameobject. The order in which gameobjects or scripts receive these functions is indeterminable, and if you want to control the order you should do it using your own even controller/listener.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b I already know when Start or Awake will run. However, what I'm curious about is that I want to know which class runs first when Awake's functions are written in different classes. And I want to know some information about why it works this way.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html

Answer (score 2):

The order between scripts is intentionally indeterminate unless you specify that order in the Script Execution Order window, which has a performance penalty.

In general, the answer is: Do not assume execution order.

If you have to rely on execution order, but don't want the performance penalty of forcing it, then write in your own flags to let other scripts know when the source script is fully initialized and ready for action.